# HTML view not updating windows 10 edge and internet explorer

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I tried loading list of courses from mongodb to my SPA using node API and angular js it works perfectly on firefox and chrome but on edge and internet explorer i have to restart the browser before it works

```
Here is what i did

router.get('/student/getstudent/:studentid', function(req, res){
if (!req.params.studentid) {
    sendJSONresponse(res, 404, {
        "message": "Not found, studentid is required"
    });
        return;
}
Student
.findOne({_id : req.params.studentid})
.populate('department')
.populate('regCourses')
.exec(function(err, student){
    if (err) {
        sendJSONresponse(res, 404, err);
    }else{
        sendJSONresponse(res, 200, student);
    }
 });
});
```

the angular js

```
$http.get('/api/student/getstudent/' + $scope.studentid)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.student = data ;
            if($scope.student.regCourses.length != 0){
            $scope.tableState = false;
            }else{
                $scope.tableState = true;
                $scope.message = "You have not registered any course";
            }
        })
        .error(function (e) {
            return e;
        });
```

The HTML

```
   <tbody> 
                     <tr ng-repeat="course in student.regCourses"> 
                        <td>{{course.name}}</td> 
                        <td>{{course.code}}</td> 
                        <td>{{course.unit}}</td> 
                        <td>{{course.Lecturer}}</td> 
                        <td><button ng-click="remove(course._id)"  class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Remove</button></td> 
                     </tr> 
         </tbody>
```

somebody help pls?

Comment: Have you tried $scope.$apply()?

Comment: no i have not tried that can you show me how to use the $scope.$apply()